# When to consider setting actions on routes or controllers?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Apparently, you can define `actions` in the `routes` or the `controllers`.

```
  actions: {
    foo: function() {
      // Do something here
    }
  }
```

Is there a rule of thumb, when considering where to put an action? Or does this come down to a matter of preference?

Comment: I think its better to have them in controllers. If you have an action on the page it bubbles up so the controller is the first place it checks and I think, the preferred place to have them, unless depending on the functionality you need it in the route.

Comment: @Craicerjack You will have the defender of the opposite coming to you Soon, it's a sensitive mater :) however i tend to do same. In fact it's depends on your application architecture.

Comment: @MrVinz it usually does come down to preference doesnt it? Anyway this will all be changing with the arrival of ember 2.0 and the removal of controllers...

Comment: I agree with the above. Only time I'd put it in the route is if it was a shared action amoung all child routes.

Comment: So if controllers are going to be removed in 2.0. Is it sane to define actions in routes?

Comment: There will be routable components in Ember 2.0, though. The details are all still being decided. But with well-tested code, you can upgrade piecemeal when you have time.